# Filter unique values from a tsv file

Tags: ruby, csv

I have a tsv file that has four columns. I'm having difficulty isolating the first column of the file (UUID), so I can strip out  the 'UUID=' from each element, and also filter from unique values.

What am I doing wrong in my code? I've been pretty stuck on figuring this out. Thank you in advance!

Here's the link to the file, and my code below.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mGaK3n3YCrzrwOgSo5QQZ62FXDKJ3nZ8/view?usp=sharing

```
require "csv"

log_file = CSV.foreach("output_file.tsv",{:col_sep => "\t", :headers => true}) do |row|

uuid = row["UUID"]
ip = row["IP"]
time = row["TIME"]
ua = row["UA"]

uuid = uuid.drop(1)
ip = ip.drop(1)
time = time.drop(1)
ua = ua.drop(1)

uuid = uuid.map { |element| 
element = element[5..-1]}

unique_logins = uuid.uniq

puts uuid.uniq.length
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably you're confused a bit and think that `CSV.foreach` reads the whole column, but it actually reads your file row by row. That's why no need to `drop(1)`.

This is the minimal code, which collects uuids from the file and prints the number of those uuids and then prints the number of unique uuids

```
require "csv"

uuids = []

log_file = CSV.foreach("output_file.tsv",{:col_sep => "\t", :headers => true}) do |row|
  uuids << row["UUID"]
end

uuids = uuids.map { |element| element = element[5..-1]}

p uuids.length
unique_logins = uuids.uniq
p unique_logins.length
```

Comment: Thank you so much Igor!! This helps so much. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

If your file isn't that big, you could also just read the entire file in at once, and then use the returned [`CSV::Table`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV/Table.html) to read the entire column out and operate on that:

```
require 'csv'
tsv = CSV.read("output_file.tsv", col_sep: "\t", headers: true)
uuids = tsv['UUID'].map { |uuid| uuid[/\AUUID=(.+)\z/, 1] }.uniq
# => ["e9fc3b6e6641e69fb8cfbdfac48709ae", "f296020354e8c913454f62732d0e3dc4",
#     "0300481b1e495e3c919b5214dda7b26c", "9ccc4096ed1d11d1b4c9e57ca1192176",
#     "c0580eeb3f98d9c3fe232fc48694bf8e", "25ee63a754b9d4590b69b9ab2a4668cd",
#     "aa61387f01797a839ca6f55daeb69b30", "9c7f37f5c187f662eaf7d0df83ac8804"]
```